# Plotting a heat map for an upper or lower triangular matrix

Tags: r, graphics, matrix, heatmap

Can any body suggest a function to plot heat map for upper or lower triangular matrix in R

Comment: If you want image to "look" like a lower triangular matrix as joran constructed, then use `image(1:10,1:10,M[,10:1])`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The most basic way to do something like this would be using `?image` as follows:

```
M <- matrix(runif(100),10,10)
M[lower.tri(M)] <- NA
image(1:10,1:10,M)
```

which would result in something like this:

[image]

You could also investigate the functions `?heatmap` or in the `gplots` package `?heatmap.2`. Doing this using `ggplot2` using `geom_tile` is a little different but you can find some examples to walk you through the process [here](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/ggplot2-quick-heatmap-plotting/).

Comment: The image didn't seem to get posted correctly but the answer is so clear it might not need one.

Comment: @DWin - Hmm...can you be more specific, my browser is displaying it fine. Maybe a SO hiccup?

Comment: Yes. it's there now in florid colors. Hicc, Hicc.