# How to easily visualize a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, visualization

When doing matrix operations, I would like to be able to see what the results of my calculations are, at least to get a rough idea of the nature of the matrices going in and coming out of the operation.

How can I plot a matrix of real numbers, so that the x axis represents columns, the y represents rows, and the color or size of a point represents the cell value?

Ultimately, I would like to display multiple plots, e.g. the right and left hand sides of an equation.

Here is some example code:

```
a <- matrix(rnorm(100), ncol = 10)
b <- diag(1,10)
c <- a*b

par(mfrow = c(1,3))
plot.matrix.fn <- function(m) {
   #enter answer to this question here
}
lapply(list(a,b,c), plot.matrix.fn)
```

update: since posting this question, I found that there are some great examples here: [What techniques exists in R to visualize a "distance matrix"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081066/what-techniques-exists-in-r-to-visualize-a-distance-matrix)

Comment: Check out this recent post, too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883618/plotting-a-heat-map-for-an-upper-or-lower-triangular-matrix

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could try something like (adjusting the parameters to your particular needs)

```
   image(t(m[nrow(m):1,] ), axes=FALSE, zlim=c(-4,4), col=rainbow(21))
```

producing something like

[image]

Answer (score 7):

See `?image` for a single plot (note that row 1 will be at the bottom) and `?rasterImage` for adding 1 or more representations to an existing plot.  You may want to do some scaling or other transformation on the matrix first.

Comment: that is pretty much what I am looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Not an answer but a longer comment.

I've been working on a package to plot matrices using `grid.raster`, but it's not quite ready for release yet. Your example would read,

```
library(gridplot)
row_layout(a, b, c)
```

[image: layout]

I found that writing custom functions was probably easier than tweaking 10s of parameters in `lattice` or base graphics, and `ggplot2` lacks some control over the axes.

However, writing graphics functions from scratch also means reinventing non-trivial things like layout and positioning; hopefully Hadley's `scales` and `guides` packages can make this easier. I'll add the functions to `gridExtra` when the overall design seems sound and more stable.